# How to one hot encode list values on row based way in python?

Tags: python, one-hot-encoding

To explain what I want to do, I show the example.

At first, my data is like this.

Data1)

Column A : 0, 1, 2 (total 3 classes)

Column B : 0, 1, 2 (total 3 classes)

```
A B
1 1
0 0
2 1
```

Then I did one hot encoding for column A and B.
After one-hot encoding, my data looks like this.

Data2)

```
Index col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6  
  0    0    1    0    0    1    0
  1    1    0    0    1    0    0
  2    0    0    1    1    0    0
```

Let's say I have so much data like data2.
Then, I want to do one hot encoding the dataframe data2.
In this case, the values of index 0, 1, 2 are different from each other in data2.
So if I do one hot encoding on data2, Then my result should be

Data3)

```
Index col1 col2 col3  
  0    1    0    0  
  1    0    1    0 
  2    0    0    1
```

like this.

How can I do this in python?
In other words, I want to do one hot encoding for every element in dataframe

Comment: this is a little confusing  ; firstly in data. 2 your cols 4,5 dont correspond to B=1,0,1, secondly im not clear on how data3 relates to data2 - do you want to onehot  encode the index? The data  is already one-hot encoded, and one-hotting data2 would actually give you 12 columns not 3 since one-hotting a binary column will give you two output columns.

Comment: In the data example, I did one hot encoding in A and B column. So column A is divided into col1, col2, col3 and Column B is divided into col4, col5, and col6. Then, in data2, every index has different value. So if I do one-hot encoding in data2, it can have 3 classes(because index 0, 1, 2 has different value in data 2). This is what I wanted to say

Comment: I just want to know how to do one-hot encoding to all elements in row based way.

Comment: you want to transpose data2 maybe? What exactly is data3 encoding??

Comment: I think I got it - you want to one-hot encode the column-wise concatenated values from transpose(data2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the hunch that you want to encode the various possible row sequences, you can do:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,0,2],'B':[1,0,1]})
In [40]: df
Out[40]:
   A  B
0  1  1
1  0  0
2  2  1    

A_oh = pd.get_dummies(df.A,prefix='A')
B_oh = pd.get_dummies(df.B,prefix='B')
df_oh = pd.concat([A_oh,B_oh],axis=1)
In [41]: df_oh
Out[41]:
   A_0  A_1  A_2  B_0  B_1
0    0    1    0    0    1
1    1    0    0    1    0
2    0    0    1    0    1

df_concat = df_oh.apply(lambda r:str(''.join(str(r[col]) for col in df_oh.columns)),axis=1)    
df_concat
Out[37]:
0    01001
1    10010
2    00101
dtype: object

pd.get_dummies(df_concat)
Out[39]:
   00101  01001  10010
0      0      1      0
1      0      0      1
2      1      0      0
```